# How can I import an image from the express server to the client (in React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, express

I'm trying to show an image in react, which is neither a local image (in the client) nor an external image from the web but an image that is in the node.js express server (and I don't want to call it as if it was an external image, because the domain could change and it just doesn't seem right).

I know I can't just import it like I do with a local image in the client because we're speaking about different localhosts. I did try this:

```
loadImage = async (imageUrl) => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/images/${imageUrl}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ image: data });
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { imageUrl } = this.props;
    try {
        this.loadImage(imageUrl);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Hay un error: " + error);
    }
}

render() {
    const { image } = this.state;
    return( 
        <div>
            <div>
                <img alt="dontknowyet" className="blog-list-image" src={image} // and so on...
```

{image} does receive the correct path, but the image won't load and the console throws this error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Dafna/Desktop/adrian/proyectos/esteticand/img/t4.jpg

So how can I make it work? and in case that I need to import the image file instead of just the link, how can I do that? (I can't update the state with an image...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the path of the image it has to be done through the express server.

For example, if the (backend) server is running on port 4500 and the image is in a folder called images, and the express variable is called app, in the server file you have to use:

```
app.use(express.static('images'));
```

and then the image can be accessed in http://localhost:4500/*nameoftheimage.jpg*.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the api running on the same port as the React app?
You usually would make them run on different ports. Maybe it's got something to do with it.

Comment: They are in different ports (3000 and 80). The website is working fine and it is interacting between the servers.